# How to hide 1 of 2 legends in ggplot2 geom_hex

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this geom_hex plot that has both a fill color and an outline color defined. I want to eliminate the legend for the outline (it says 'count' above it) and keep the fill legend (which says 'Freq'). Link below shows the image of the plot.

```
plotX <- ggplot(data = rt28, aes(x = TimeNumericValue, y = load)) +
  geom_hex(aes(colour = ..count..))
plotX + labs(
  title = 'Route 28 Bus Ridership',
  subtitle = 'Fall 2016 - Fall 2019',
  x = 'Time of Day',
  y = 'Average Passenger Load',
  fill = 'Freq') +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: See Plot Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two options to achieve your desired result. Remove the color legend with `+ guides(color = "none")` or use the same name for the color legend as for the fill using `+ labs(..., color = "Freq")` so that both legends get merged.

Using the `ggplot2::diamonds` dataset as example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) + 
  geom_hex(aes(colour = ..count..)) + 
  labs(
  title = 'Route 28 Bus Ridership',
  subtitle = 'Fall 2016 - Fall 2019',
  x = 'Time of Day',
  y = 'Average Passenger Load',
  fill = 'Freq') +
  theme_minimal()

d + labs(color = "Freq")
```

[image]

```r
d + guides(color = "none")
```

[image]